# How to find x and y in this vector question if P is in equilibrium?

Tags: vectors

[picture of the diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmt2R.png)

This is what i tried:
sum of upward forces= sum of downward forces

x sin 90 + y sin 60 - 8 sin 30

x sin 90 + y sin 60 - 4

sum of forces to the right= sum of forces to the left

7 + x cos 90 - y cos 60 - 8 cos 30

7 + x cos 90 - y cos 60 - 6.93

x cos 90 - y cos 60 + 1.93

and i lost myself here....please help!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  One possible reason why you're stuck is because your solution is poorly formatted.

A loose definition of equilibrium in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is if $\Sigma \overrightarrow{f_x}=0$ and $\Sigma \overrightarrow{f_y}=0$.  Knowing this:

\begin{align}
\Sigma \overrightarrow{f_x}=0&=7-y\cos60^{\circ}-8\cos30^{\circ}\\
0&=7-\frac12y-4\sqrt3\\
\Sigma \overrightarrow{f_y}=0&=x+y\sin60^{\circ}-8\sin30^{\circ}\\
0&=x+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}y-4\\
\end{align}

You now have two equations with two variables.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: ok so with these two equations im assuming i work them simultaneously and that should  yield my x and y values?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct assumption.